# Checking if a ZonedDateTime is between a certain time

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I am getting the time and date of a location with the code below

```
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeForAccount = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
        System.out.println(dateAndTimeForAccount);
```

How can I check if `dateAndTimeForAccount` is between 6am to 10am?

Comment: please revisit the accepted answer. It returns TRUE for edge cases of "10:01"-"10:59", that would compromise new readers, who'll be taking it as the "6 to 10" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution could be to use a [ValueRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html).

NOTE: the below solution will result in **true** for **10:59** (see "Corner case output" at the very bottom:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeForAccount = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
System.out.println(dateAndTimeForAccount);

ValueRange hourRange = ValueRange.of(8, 10);
System.out.printf("is hour (%s) in range [%s] -> %s%n", 
        dateAndTimeForAccount.getHour(),
        hourRange, 
        hourRange.isValidValue(dateAndTimeForAccount.getHour())
);
```

example output

```
2017-01-11T07:34:26.932-05:00[America/New_York]
is hour (7) in range [8 - 10] -> false
```

**edit**: The snippet guides as an example for the suggested solution. It's not a full solution and as visible in the code it only makes a check on the hour part.

**Corner case output:** results in **true** for **10:59**:

```
2017-01-11T10:59:59.999-05:00[America/New_York]
is hour (10) in range [8 - 10] -> true
```

Comment: @epox I removed your edit from the post. **1)** the snippet shows cleary that it takes only the hour part into account (in the code and in the example output) **2)** the answer was accepted by the OP, so it seems the snippet was enough to find his/her solution

Answer (score 2):

## is between `6 am` inclusive to `10 am` exclusive

This should be enough for *"99%"* of cases as *"you"* cannot guarantee JVM clock is more than 1 milliseconds precise.

```
    return 6 <= t.getHour() && t.getHour() < 10;
```

---

## Is between `6 to 10 am` inclusive

```
  static final LocalTime OPEN_TIME = LocalTime.of(06, 00);
  static final LocalTime CLOSE_TIME = LocalTime.of(10, 00);

    return !t.toLocalTime().isBefore(OPEN_TIME) && !t.toLocalTime().isAfter(CLOSE_TIME);
```

---

## Is between `6 to 10 am` exclusive

```
    return t.toLocalTime().isAfter(OPEN_TIME) && t.toLocalTime().isBefore(CLOSE_TIME);
```

---

Proof:

```
  boolean isWithinSixToTen(ZonedDateTime t) {
    return 6 <= t.getHour() && t.getHour() < 10;
  }



import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

  ZonedDateTime time(String time) {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-01-11" + "T" + time + "-05:00[America/New_York]");
  }

    assertThat(isWithinSixToTen(time("10:01"))).isFalse();
    assertThat(isWithinSixToTen(time("10:00"))).isFalse();
    assertThat(isWithinSixToTen(time("09:59:59.999999999"))).isTrue();
    assertThat(isWithinSixToTen(time("06:00"))).isTrue();
    assertThat(isWithinSixToTen(time("05:59"))).isFalse();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentHour = dateAndTimeForAccount.getHour();
boolean isBetween6And10 = 6 <= currentHour && currentHour <= 10;
```

If you want to generalize it for any specific java.time class you can use the `TemporalQuery` class:

```
class HourTester extends TemporalQuery<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean queryFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        int hour = temporal.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        return 6 <= hour && hour <= 10;
    }
}
```

Usage: `boolean isBetween6And10 = dateAndTimeForAccount.query(new HourTester());`